# Does a fiend drop any items carried when it is killed and returned to Avernus?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, equipment

I had a bearded devil carrying some keys that would open a jail cell, tied to his belt and was slain.
My question is, does it drop the keys and can be retrieved by my players or would they go with it back to Avernus?

I am not too concerned if I have to make my own ruling but if this has been answered somewhere I would prefer to use that rule.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* suggests that they don't keep their equipment.

*Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* discusses at great length the lore of the war between devils and demons, known as the Blood War. It speaks of the potential for a devilish incursion beyond Avernus, and mentions an issue this can cause for their equipment, in the section [Cosmic Battlefield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mtof/the-blood-war#CosmicBattlefield) (MToF, pg. 7):

> If the devils extended a tenacious defense out to the planes beyond Avernus, they could keep the demons away from Hell’s doorstep, but such a strategy would place a great strain on supplies, reinforcements, and unit integrity. Although the devils killed in such places would recover, *their weapons, armor, and other materials would remain lost.*

So when the [*Monster Manual* says](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-d#TheInfernalHierarchy) (MM, pg. 67):

> If it dies outside the Nine Hells, a devil disappears in a cloud of sulfurous smoke or dissolves into a pool of ichor, instantly returning to its home layer, where it reforms at full strength.

I take this to mean that the devil itself, which does not include things it is carrying disappears, leaving behind what it was carrying, as suggested in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*.

Comment: It's also worth noting that many/most items (e.g. weapons) carried by monsters don't necessarily have any special effect when wielded by a player character. (I think there's a Q&A about that...)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a specific rule stating either way, but in my experience, it makes the most sense both mechanically (game logic) and lore-wise to have summoned creatures take the gear *that they brought with them / were summoned with* back home when they're banished or slain, but things they've picked up on the Prime Material since should be left behind.

In total, there are three real options to pick from:

1. They take everything they're carrying back with them.  This includes magical items (and *possibly* artifacts) they just stole earlier in the round they're slain, moving them someplace generally considered "forever out of reach".
2. Only their body vanishes, and all their gear stays.  If your players have the ability to summon any creature whose stat block includes equipment, they now have an effectively infinite source of that equipment for a spell slot or two.
3. The middle option - the creature and the gear that is "part of it" when summoned go back, but the important keys they've picked up while here or the sword they just snatched from the Fighter drop to the ground.

3 makes the most sense to me.

Comment: What has been your experience when using these ideas?